# unable to retrieve countDownTimer left timeMillis value when activity resumed

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I started countDownTimer when activity starts and the **milliRemaining** variable is declared globally

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(120000 , 1000){

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            millisRemaining = millisUntilFinished;

            seconds = (long) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            minutes = seconds / 60;
            seconds = seconds % 60;
            mCountdownTimerTextView.setText(String.format("%02d", minutes)
                    + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds));

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            mCountdownTimerTextView.setText("Done");
        }
    }.start();

}
```

In savedInstance method stores value of millisRemaining

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putLong("millisLeft" , millisRemaining);

}
```

and In restoreInstancestate method I'm calling **onTick** method passing **millisRemaining**

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    millisRemaining = savedInstanceState.getLong("millisleft");

    System.out.println(millisRemaining/1000);

    countDownTimer.onTick(millisRemaining);
}
```

it shows time correctly till the activity is not paused. I am new to android , please correct me . Also , I'm implementing this in right way or not .

**UPDATE**

Here is code of the Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private long seconds , minutes , millisRemaining;
CountDownTimer countDownTimer = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(120000 , 1000){

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            millisRemaining = millisUntilFinished;

            seconds = (long) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            minutes = seconds / 60;
            seconds = seconds % 60;
            mCountdownTimerTextView.setText(String.format("%02d", minutes)
                    + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds));

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            mCountdownTimerTextView.setText("Done");
        }
    }.start();

    @Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

    outState.putLong("millisLeft" , millisRemaining);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    millisRemaining = savedInstanceState.getLong("millisleft");

    System.out.println(millisRemaining/1000);

    countDownTimer.onTick(millisRemaining);
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put the code from `onStart()` to `onCreate()`. For better understanding see the [App Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)

**EDIT:**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(120000, 1000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            millisRemaining = millisUntilFinished;

            seconds = (long) (millisUntilFinished / 1000);
            minutes = seconds / 60;
            seconds = seconds % 60;
            mCountdownTimerTextView.setText(String.format("%02d", minutes)
                    + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds));

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            mCountdownTimerTextView.setText("Done");
        }
    }.start();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

}
```